# sending confirmation email using in php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a php code for sending confirmation email. But how to send this email to registered user using my mail server. Example using gmail to send confirmarion email.

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit; 
        } else { 
           $username = $_POST['username']; 
           $email = $_POST['email']; 
           $password = $_POST['password']; 
           $com_code = md5(uniqid(rand()));

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password, com_code) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$com_code')"; $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

        if($result2) { 
            $to = $email; 
            $subject = "Confirmation from  MyName to $username"; 
            $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb"; 
            $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. rn"; $message .= "http://www.yourname.com/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";

        $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

        if($sentmail) { 
           echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address."; 
        } else { 
          echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address"; 
        } 
     } 
  } 
 } 
?>
```

Comment: First format your question and make it a little more easy to read

Answer (score 0):

If you have your mail servers credentials then you can use SMTP to send emails. You can also use [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which is very easy to use.

First thing is you need to install PHPMailer from above link after that use following code
   `

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;


$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';                 // Your gmail username
$mail->Password = 'your_gmail_password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'from@example.com'; // from email address
$mail->FromName = 'User1'; // whatever is the name of sender
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['username']);     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    =  $message ;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>`
```

Comment: Sir that part is confusing me. Please edit my code with sample mailserver setup using gmail. Thank you sir.

Comment: it will works on localhost computer(in my desktop xampp server ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have mail server then you follow the your mail server rules.

You can use ***PHPMailer*** and follow the rule of phpmailer function.

Comment: Can u edit y above code with php mailer using samle gmail id and pass. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Fix : You have to find out whether you have installed a mail server in your server instance. This depends on server environment. You can find how to with simple web search. 
Tip: If just get the response from the operation as normal your mail server is not connected. But if it's keep waiting for like 4 to 5 seconds means most of the time server is there issue is something in it. 
Ubuntu - [How to install postfix][1]
Windows - [SMTP E-mail][2]

Further issues :
Once you can send the mail using php mail function but still you have give the accurate header information otherwise the mail will send to spam folder.

Wrong:    $header = "TutsforWeb: Confirmation from TutsforWeb"; 
 Correct:
`$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();`

If you want to do it gmail just refer this : [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/)

Answer (score 0):

You  first fetch data from table where registered users are stored then you can send mail to registered users

Answer (score 0):

```
Download PHPMailerAutoload
```

[link here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/downloads/PHPMailerAutoload.zip)

```
<?php

// When we unzipped PHPMailer, it unzipped to
// public_html/PHPMailer_5.2.0

require("lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

// we are setting the HOST to localhost
$mail->Host = "mail.example.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

// When sending email using PHPMailer, you need to send from a valid email address
// In this case, we setup a test email account with the following credentials:
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "from@example.com";

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("to@example.com", "To whom");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";
$message = "Text Message";
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```